# Moral philosophy book to read after James Rachel's "The elements of moral philosophy"

Tags: ethics, reference-request

I am new to philosophy and I've made my entry by reading the exquisite textbook "The elements of moral philosophy" by James Rachel.
I'd like to get into more depth (but not more than I can handle) in the various theories presented in this textbook as well as new theories, maybe even more modern ones.
What book or textbook would you suggest I read next?